Помогите пожалуйста, пишу тг бота
Вот ошибка:
in db_table_val
   cursor.execute(f"select count(*) from apple where user_id = {user_id}")
sqlite3.DatabaseError: database disk image is malformed


Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе.

У вас повреждена база данных. Если имеющиеся там данные не столь важны, вы можете пересоздать базу данных.
Создать базу данных на sqlite3 можно следующим образом:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS apple ( user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, username TEXT NOT NULL, priglasil_id INTEGER)


А как  ее пересоздать?

Как указано в ответе, только в скобках должны быть указаны необходимые вам столбцы.

Я через вот этот код создаю:
'''
import sqlite3
with sqlite3.connect('database.db') as conn:
conn.execute(''' CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS apple (
user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
username TEXT NOT NULL,
priglasil_id INTEGER
)  ''')
'''
Три раза уже переделывал пишет что она все равно сломана
Я добавил фото как она выглядит.

Удалите старую базу данных, как файл, и создайте новую через sql команду.

Прошу прощение, а что это за команда и как она выглядит?

Файл с базой данных удалите

А потом заново пропишите CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS apple ( user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, username TEXT NOT NULL, priglasil_id INTEGER

Это нужно ввести в терминал?

В каком терминале? Когда вы обращаетесь через метод conn.execute, вставьте это в аргумент функции. Как в оригинальном сообщении. Но только, если вы удалили старый файл с базой данных.

БД повреждена, но вы можете создать новую. В python это будет выглядеть так:
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect("database.db") # Подключаемся к БД
cursor = connection.cursor()

# Формируем SQL-запрос
sql = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS apple(
user_id INTEGER PRIMARY_KEY,
username TEXT NOT NULL,
priglasil_id INTEGER,
admin INTEGER)"""

cursor.execute(sql) # Отправляем запрос

